# Is Learning With App Inventor A Bad Idea For Novice Developers?

Tags: java, android

I've been interested in learning about app development after taking a college class in Java. I watched a video tutorial about App Inventor by Derek Banas (he covers amazing tutorials and I highly recommend him). I'm slightly concerned because as I was watching the tutorial I could understand how to code some of the "blocks" by using java.

So my question is would it be better to simply stick with expanding my Java knowledge, or should I pick up app inventor as an additional skill? I just don't want to spend hours learning how to use app inventor only to realize that my time would have been better spent learning Java.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not well-suited for questions seeking opinions like this, and so they are considered to be off-topic. If by "additional skill" you are referring to something with respect to employment, you might consider searching job sites and comparing how many prospective employers are seeking Java programmers versus how many are seeking App Inventor users.

Comment: question does not belong hiere - off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your objective. App Inventor is a great introduction to programming, but there are limits to the types of apps you can build with it. For those with some java experience, App Inventor is a great tool for rapid prototyping and teaching, but that's about it. Given you already have some java exposure, I would recommend you continue down that path and learn native android development. There are great free resources available that can help your learning curve. Here is a very good one: https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

Note: Many GDG (Google Developer Groups) are organizing study groups based the free Udacity course in 2015Q1. You may want to see if your local group is one of them - https://developers.google.com/groups/directory/